# alternate between two functions on click

Tags: jquery

How do I alternate between calling two functions on click? For example, here is the button

```
<div id="fooButton" />
```

and here is the javascript

```
function fooOne() {
     alert('foo One called');
}

function fooTwo() {
     alert('foo Two called');
}
```

how do I call fooOne() and fooTwo() on alternate button clicks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [toggle pseudo-event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

```
$('#fooButton').toggle(fooOne, fooTwo);
```

Note: This is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9+. You can use [jQuery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) if you need this function anyway.

Comment: this has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.8  -- so it should not be used any longer.

Comment: Indeed. but in 2011 there was no jquery 1.8 yet :)

Comment: Ha! Notice how time keeps passing no matter what? Anyone reading this will be doing so after 2011 :P

Comment: Is there a way to do this in jQuery 1.9.* without replying on jQuery-migrate?

Answer (score 6):

Use jQuery's toggle() method

```
$("#fooButton").toggle(fooOne, fooTwo);
```

Edited to make use of your named functions rather than sloppily using anonymous ones.