# jquery click replace, click again replace

Tags: jquery

just a quick question, how do i tell jquery to action1 on first click, and when the user clicks again it should do action then restart actions? 
ex: the user clicks like, the text should change to unlike, when the user presses unlike, it should change to like, and so on..

```
<a href="#" class="like">Like</a>

$('.like').click(function(){
//ajax
    $(this).html('Remove like');
},function(){
    $(this).html('like');
});
```

but it only seems to work once, like when the user have clicked it changes to remove like and when i click again nothing happends

Comment: possible duplicate of [alternate between two functions on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891029/alternate-between-two-functions-on-click)

Comment: `click` only accepts one function, which is clearly described in the documentation. Why do you think it accepts two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [jquery toggle handler](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

```
.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject) [, handler(eventObject)] )

handler(eventObject)  A function to execute every even time the element is clicked.
handler(eventObject)  A function to execute every odd time the element is clicked.
handler(eventObject)  Additional handlers to cycle through after clicks.
```

E.g.:

```
$('.like').toggle(function() {
    //ajax
    $(this).html('Remove like');
}, function() {
    $(this).html('like');
});
```

Comment: dam i saw that toggle function before, but i didnt think it would work D:
thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var first = true;

$('.like').click(function(){
  if(first){
    $(this).html('Remove like');
    first = false;
}else{

    $(this).html('like');
    first = true;
}
});
```

Alternatively:

```
var first = true;

$('.like').click(function(){
  var text = "";
    ($(this).html() == "like"){
       text = "Remove like";
    }else{
       text = "like";
    }
    $(this).html(text)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this as follows

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="like" id="button">Like</a>
```

Jquery

```
$("#button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass('like'))
    {

        $(this).html('Remove like');
        $(this).removeClass("like");
        $(this).addClass("unlike");
    }else{

        $(this).html('like');
        $(this).removeClass("unlike");
        $(this).addClass("like");
    }

});
```

Live [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MQtrq/11/)

Edit:
More simple

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('like'))
    {        
        $(this).html('Remove like');
        $(this).toggleClass("like unlike");

    }else{        
        $(this).html('like');
        $(this).toggleClass("like unlike");
    }

});
```

Comment: Seems to be much more complicated than `toggle`.

Comment: @Felix Kling Check the edit... I think now its simple. What say??