# Resetting click function on next click

Tags: jquery, onclick

HI I have created a jcarousel and I want each pager item in the jcarousel to be faded until the user clicks to view the slide this is the current jquery I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.overlay').css('display', 'block');
    $('.overlay').css('opacity', 1.0);
    $('.views_slideshow_jcarousel_pager_item').click(function() {
        $('.overlay', this).stop().animate({opacity:0.0},500);
    },
    function() 
        $('.overlay').stop().animate({opacity:1.0},500);
    });
});
```

It's kind of working but it stays in the click state, anybody got any ideas on how to fix this?  The dev site is at [dev.shoeboxdesign.co.uk](http://dev.shoeboxdesign.co.uk)

Comment: possible duplicate of [alternate between two functions on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891029/alternate-between-two-functions-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i get it, but shouldn't it be:

```
$('.views_slideshow_jcarousel_pager_item').click(function() {
    $('.overlay', this).stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function() {
        $('.overlay').stop().animate({opacity: 1},500);
    });
});
```

Looks to me like your closing the first animation and then are trying to run a new function or something strange. there's just too many characters there?

Maybe you are trying to do a toggle? Who knows.

Also, you are animating back in all elements with the class .overlay, and not just the one you animated out, for that you could just use $(this) in the second animation, if that is the intended effect that is.